# Can Fleeting Spring 5 force a changeling to break her Motley Pledge?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, changeling-the-lost

A successful invocation of a Contract of Fleeting Spring (•••••) (aka. *Waking the Inner Faerie*) means

> the target feels the immediate impulse to try to achieve one of his greatest desires. He 
>   abandons other responsibilities and rational thinking to obey that urge.

Suppose a changeling's greatest desire is to kill her motley-mate.  Would following that desire while under the influence of the above contract be considered pledge-breaking?

(For those who care, the in-game situation is that this motley pledge was made as a defensive bargain: enemies join together for a period to fight a common *greater* enemy.)

Comment: Congratulations question #5000!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is "**yes**." The *motley pledge* is a Vow of Greater Alliance, which means that those so pledged will defend each other even under pain of torture or death, so someone who indulged their desire to kill their motley-mate under Fleeting Spring 5 would certainly have broken their pledge. These are mythic promises and faerie-tale contracts, and all technicalities count. If you harbor the desire to kill your motley mate, and someone uses that desire to get you to try and kill them, that's the way it goes.

However, at its core the question's premise is nonsensical. Why would someone swear a motley pledge, enforced by the Wyrd, and burn a permanent Willpower dot to seal it, with someone who they deeply, sincerely desired to kill? Why would a person choose to *be* in a motley with an enemy like that? Such a person would have poison at the heart of their Oath.

As regards your edit: you guys picked the wrong pledge. :) You should have gone with the Good Neighbors' Pact, or crafted your own custom pledge to give you more leeway for that kind of accidental treachery. Using the motley pledge as written is just signing your death warrant.

Comment: Is the question of whether she has a choice to follow her desire relevant?  (And: *does* she have a choice?)  (Finally: edited the post to explain the in-game situation, fwiw.)

Comment: Not especially. These are mythic promises and faerie-tale contracts, and all technicalities count. If you harbor the desire to kill your motley mate, and someone uses that desire to *get* you to try and kill them, that's the way it goes. As for "do you have a choice"? Well, that depends. The power is an extended contest where the attacker needs to accumulate a number of net successes equal to the defender's Willpower. Spend WP, boost that roll, and get the hell out of that situation before the Contract succeeds. That's your "choice." Once it's complete, though, you do as your desire commands.